# Embedding with HTML - With a new link each time

Tags: javascript, html, variables, hyperlink, embed

I have this code so far.

```
<html>

<object data=http://www.tagpro.eu width="850" height="800"> <embed src=http://www.tagpro.eu width="650" height="700"> </embed></object>

</html>
```

And i have a form.

```
<form>
Game:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<br>
Link:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
```

What i need:

If the form, whatever the link is, set the embed website to that certain link. For example if in the form i write google in the link section and click submit, you will see the webpage of google on my site.

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have adapted your code like this:

```
<form id="demo-form">
    Game:<br>
    <input type="text" name="game" id="game" value="bootstrap datepicker">
    <br>
    Link:<br>
    <input type="text" name="link" id="link" value="https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>

<object id="demo-object" data=https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ width="850" height="800">
    <!--<embed src=http://www.tagpro.eu width="650" height="700"> </embed>-->
</object>
```

and I used some javascript as follows:

```
document.getElementById("demo-form").onsubmit = function () {
    var game = document.getElementById("game").value;
    var link = document.getElementById("link").value;
    document.getElementById("demo-object").setAttribute('data', link)
    // Return false to prevent the default form behavior
    return false;
}
```

Please check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marianc/bm65hnnp/). However this does not work on every site. For instance I got an error trying to use google link. Also this demo works in Firefox 39.0 and Internet Explorer 9 but not in Chrome 43.0.2357.130. However outside fiddle it worked in Chrome too.

If you need to keep the selection between page refresh, one possible solution would be to store the selection in a cookie by using [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)
 and the code will change as follows:

```
if ($.cookie("link")) {
    // Restore the last selection from cookie
    document.getElementById("link").value = $.cookie("link");
    document.getElementById("demo-object").setAttribute('data', $.cookie("link"))
}
document.getElementById("demo-form").onsubmit = function () {
    var game = document.getElementById("game").value;
    var link = document.getElementById("link").value;
    document.getElementById("demo-object").setAttribute('data', link)
    // Store the selection in a cookie
    $.cookie("link", link);
    // Return false to prevent the default form behavior
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I used the fiddle and tried about 10 sites, none seem to work? I don't know if this is because of fiddle?

Comment: Nevermind, i ran it on my server and it worked. But, when i refresh it goes away. How do i make it stay forever on the page that i entered?

Comment: I have adapted the answer to keep selection between page refresh.